# Minimizing error in cosine similarity

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Presume I have a vector space, and I am attempting to compress it into a latent vector space, while minimizing error in cosine similarity between entries. Suppose that I know the actual cosine similarity scores between the latent space. i.e.

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be my set of vectors, and $r: X \times X \to [-1, 1]$ be a function. I am trying to find a function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that the error $$\sum_{(x, y) \in X \times X} |sim(f(x), f(y)) - r(x, y)|$$ is minimized.

What is a good way of finding $f$ given $X$, $r$ and $m$? I am comfortable using gradient descent or neural networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the necessary function using error back propagation, you only need to design the **architecture of the neural network**, which will represent the desired function (for example, several layers, activation functions, etc.).

I do not see any problems when using the function you specified as a loss function. Because cosine similarity in this case is the product vector embeddings, then the gradient is calculated obviously.

I recommend that you study how **face recognition** models are trained (for example, [Facenet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03832)). Very similar approaches are used there.

I'm pretty sure you're aware of the use of **Kullback–Leibler divergence** to solve this problem. I just wanted to draw attention to the possible use of SGD for its optimization, which may give a hint in your case.

Comment: I think I had a lapse in reason! You mentioned that the gradient is obvious because of the product of vector embedding, and yes. You're right. Seeing two variables within a loss function worried me, but in this case it is trivial. Thank you very much.